# The fixed size of the div containing deleted flagged posts causes display issues on small screens

Tags: bug, flag-history, design

The flag summary page puts deleted posts in a `<div>` with

```
width: 685px
```

and

```
background-color: #f4eaea
```

which doesn't take the size of the page into account. As a result the `<div>` flows into the "*Your flagging history*" box.

The bug can be seen at its worst when resizing the window to 800px (799px and smaller shows a mobile-friendly version which doesn't have this issue), in which case it looks something like this (for obvious reasons I've redacted the salient parts of the screenshot):

> [image: Example of bad behaviour]

The fixed width can also mean that things like this can happen:

> [image: Example of bad behaviour from my meta flags]

Could this be fixed please?

Comment: Can be fixed by setting class `.answer-link` max-width to 100%. Right now it's a fixed px value.

Comment: Also reported [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/319779/flag-summary-page-is-mostly-responsive-but-post-titles-overflow-into-the-stat)

Comment: @SamuelLiew - aha: I knew it'd be something simple - hadn't pictured it being *so* simple.

Comment: Still a bug, e.g. [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/381466/1364007).

Comment: Recent changes to the flag summary page have improved this [(screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hEbmB.png) but now the div appears *behind* the table on the right [(screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eGmLA.png) so it's less of a big deal.