# Comment flag section calls comments "answers"

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, design, flag-history

As most of us know, our flag history can be viewed from our "Activity" section of the profile. But I noticed a little issue (that's what I do) when looking at the comment flagging history:

[image]

Underlined in red, it should say something like `commented`, as these are comments, but it uses `answered` (although I am clearly in my comment flags).

Comment: By design. A problematic design, but currently intentional.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This is working as intended. That text refers to the post the comments are placed on. In addition, clicking the hyperlinked question title leads you to the *post*, rather than the comment flagged.

It becomes a bit more obvious when you flag multiple comments on a single post:

[image]

Comment: But the name on 'answered by' was of the commenter?

Comment: @JerryD Nope, it shows the author of the post, not the comment.

Comment: Ok, I see. But either way shouldn't it show the commenter name, because it does the same with question and answer flags?