# Comment flag should link to comment

Tags: feature-request, comment-flags

In your flag summary, you can see "post flags", linking to the post you've flagged (either a question or an answer, both work), and "comment flags", [linking to the parent post that contains that comment, somewhere](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/381466/comment-flag-section-calls-comments-answers).

I think it's useful that the flag links to the comment, because it can take a while for flags to be followed up and it may be useful to be able to look back at what comment you've flagged exactly.

Also if flags are followed up by a moderator and your flag was declined, it can still be useful to go back and be able to remind yourself what kind of comments not to flag.

Can this be realized?

Comment: An actioned flag usually results in the comment being removed. Is it worth linking to a missing comment? I'm not sure if an **un**actioned flag links to the comment, however. Also I don't know if it ever did as I never tried to follow the links.

Comment: As an aside, moderators cannot (as of April 2019) leave custom comments on any comment flags ([source](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/384218/1364007)).

Comment: @Wai heh, TIL, and comment flags have a shorter text limit as well (200 as opposed to 500 or something like that). Even more reason to not use custom comment flags anymore, but flag a post of the user.

Comment: A comment flag is a binary request: "please delete this comment". Everything else is just an explanation for *why* you think the comment should be deleted. If you're flagging a comment for any other reason (e.g., a *pattern* of behavior), then don't use a comment flag. Raise a flag on the post. The note that mods can only mark comment flags as helpful/declined (by deleting or not deleting the comment) is still true, as is that we cannot include any sort of message along with the helpful/declined status is still true, and not likely to ever change. That said, this is a reasonable request.

Comment: @Cody thanks, especially for the explanation about the pattern part.