# My name is repeated everywhere in the flag summary page

Tags: support, design, flag-history

A self explanatory image:

> [image]

I am pretty sure this is something new because I never noticed this before. In all the cases, I think it doesn't make sense to have such information since all the flags are for sure *my* flags.

Comment: Probably for consistency in mod tools or something

Comment: I thought it was new when I saw your screenshot, but turns out not, e.g.: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/379814/1364007

Comment: @WaiHaLee strange, I was convinced it was new because it bothered me a lot today ..

Comment: It has been this way for as long as I can remember, _at least_ 2 months (given the screenshots I have of my own flags)

Comment: @Zoe I would expect all mod tools to say _anon_ although maybe mods do that only when sharing stuff in meta questions ;p

Comment: @Nick Not me. I change all user names to "Nick". Hopefully it'll catch on.