# The post score displayed in the flagging history appears above the name of the question

Tags: bug, design, flag-history

**tl;dr**: Post scores in flag histories are not displayed on the same line as the question title, but only on some sites.

---

This appears to be a regression of part of [The re-design has borked the user flag history page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/283617/1364007), which was marked [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed).

The [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) report reported four issues on the Stack Overflow flag summary:

1. "All the vote counts are on displayed on a separate line"
2. "there is no background on the count itself unless there is an accepted answer"
3. "the "active" tag's text color could be better (white maybe?)"
4. "the "spam" tag looks wrong and is too large for the actual text"

Issue 4 was reported on Meta Stack Exchange: [Could do with a space between the spam red box and text which follows in a user's flags list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/250727/284827). After the MSE bug report was marked [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed), [a comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283617/the-re-design-has-borked-the-user-flag-history-page#comment162703_283617) was posted stating on the MSO question:

> @Roombatron5000 This has been fixed [meta.stackexchange.com/a/250735/241622](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/250735/241622)

then the MSO question was also marked [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed), but since then there has been a regression.

---

At some point since February 2019 (when I posted [this MSO question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/379814/1364007) which displayed my flag summary with scores on different lines), the behaviour has been fixed on Stack Overflow: the flags seem to have the scores on the same line as the question title:

> [image]

but the flags on Meta Stack Overflow have scores on a different line, and the light red `div` to show a deleted post doesn't align with the right alignment of the post owner:

> [image]

This *doesn't* seem to be a Meta/main bug as the scores are on the same line on Meta Stack Exchange:

> [image]

and on Meta Super User:

> [image]

---

Upon looking at the flag summaries on a few network sites that I've raised flags on, this doesn't seem to be limited to Meta Stack Overflow:

| Site | Main | Meta |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Ask Different | Good | Bad |
| Ask Ubuntu | Bad | Good |
| Bitcoin | Good | Good |
| Drupal Answers | Bad | Bad |
| Math Overflow | Bad | Bad |
| Software Engineering | Bad | Bad |
| Stack Overflow | Good | Bad |
| Super User | Bad | Good |

Comment: This question should *probably* go on Meta Stack Exchange since I've discovered it's not limited to Stack Overflow - not sure if I should cross-post there and delete this one, or flag for migration.

Comment: I can migrate it for you, if you want. But it isn't *necessary* to post network-wide bug reports on MSE. It's fine to post them here.

Comment: @CodyGray - ah, okay. If it's fine here then it might as well stay here. Thanks.